# ATS failed system trust & system TLS Trust evaluation failed

Tags: swift, xcode, networking, nsurlsession

I'm getting this error message in my log every time my app connects to an API and fetches JSON data. Also, I would like to mention that this started happening in Xcode version 11.0 in Xcode 10.3 everything worked fine.

**Error Message:**

> ```
> ATS failed system trust
>  Connection 4: system TLS Trust evaluation failed(-9802)
>  Connection 4: TLS Trust encountered error 3:-9802
>  Connection 4: encountered error(3:-9802) Task <DCFB71BA-3D6A-4D91-9374-1D467F0BF05B>.<17> HTTP load failed, 0/0  bytes (error code: -1200 [3:-9802])
> ```

---

I tried to configure the `info.plist` but no luck.
I know `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` should be set to false for security reasons but in this situation is for testing purposes only.

**info.plist:**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>main.app.domain</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>idp.vender.domain</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

All suggestions and code samples are appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: what was issue?

Comment: did you finally solved it? @Ilija